# How to register a schedule task so that the task executes for the existing user

Tags: c++, windows, taskscheduler

I am scheduling a particular task. The task is working fine for the admin account but when I switch to the guest account nothing happens. This is part of the code which registers the task.

```
IRegisteredTask *pRegisteredTask = NULL;
    hr = pRootFolder->RegisterTaskDefinition(
            _bstr_t( wszTaskName ),
            pTask,
            TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE, 
            _variant_t(L""),
            variant_t(),
            TASK_LOGON_INTERACTIVE_TOKEN,
            variant_t(L""),
            &pRegisteredTask);
```

So, how to modify it so that the task also runs for non-admin accounts.

Comment: Have you tried running the output in admin mode. By admin mode i mean "Run as administrator".

Comment: Yes I have tried.But it is not working on other user.Only working for admin.I suspect there is something wrong with    TASK_LOGON